# Cannot find file at '..\\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\opt\bin\python.exe' Chocolatey mingw path issue

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables, mingw, chocolatey

Running `python` in powershell outputs

`Cannot find file at '..\\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\opt\bin\python.exe' (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\opt\bin\python.exe). This usually indicates a missing or moved file.`

Even after reinstalling and uninstalling mingw from choco python doesn't work and I'm getting the same message.

Removing `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\opt\bin\` from system path also doesn't fix it

Answer (score 1):

The issue is python.exe in `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin` which to me seems to be referencing the choco mingw folder. For some reason it doesn't get deleted when uninstalling along with all the other mingw executables in choco's bin folder.

The solution is to either rename `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\python.exe` or to delete it.